# Window.open not working in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

This is the JavaScript I'm currently using:

```
window.open('/modules/mod_oneononechat/chatwindow.php?key='+key+'&color=blue','x'+winName+'x','location=0,status=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,height=375,width=420');
```

This doesn't seem to be working in IE8.
It's a chat window that works fine on all other browsers (including IE7). Any ideas as to why it's not working on IE8?

Comment: Try turning off the popup blocker

Comment: tried that..doesnt work!

Comment: Which version of IE8 is this? Refer http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164539/ to report the version accurately.

Comment: That's MS IE8 RTM build. So you should be fine.

Answer (score 71):

IE8 doesn't like spaces in the window name.

Comment: This turned out to be the issue with me as well. I got an "Invalid Argument" error in the javascript debugging. Dashes don't work either but underscores worked.

Comment: Yup, same here.  
Spaces and dashes caused IE8 to reject the Open request.
Thanks for saving me many wasted hours.

Comment: I can't believe how bad IE is... Thanks for this.

Comment: Thank God for SO and people like you. Saved me a lot of wasted hours, you did. +1

Comment: This is true for IE7 as well.

Comment: i dont see a space or dash in the question !! please reply

Answer (score 4):

Removing the space from the window name solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In IE8, the below function was not opening a new window pop up whereas it was working perfectly in Mozilla and Chrome.

```
function openReports(reportUrl){
   window.open(reportUrl,'Report Information','height=800,width=1000,left=200,top=200,toolbars=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=auto,location=no');
}
```

Removing the space (Report Information)from the window name solved the problem for me too.

Comment: Removing the space from the window name solved the problem for me too.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
javascript:window.open('http://google.com', 'x'+'winName'+'x', 'location=0', 'status=0', 'toolbar=0', 'menubar=0', 'resizable=0', 'scrollbars=0', 'height=375', 'width=420');
```

Answer (score 1):

I too had a problem with this issue. I had written a function like

```
function newPopup(url) {
      popupWindow=window.open(url,'Detailed Informations','height=700,width=1000,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
```

where there was a space in the window name i.e "Detailed Information" and due to this the popup was not working. Just dont put any spaces in the window name.

Answer (score 1):

`window.open` has three parameters: `url`, `windowname`, `otherfeatures`.

For FF, if the second parameter (`windowname`) is not passed, it still works :)

But in IE 7,8 which we tested, we have to pass the second parameter

Answer (score 1):

```
var newWin = window.open('', '', 'width=400, height=400, top=100, left=100');
```

In IE8 Use This first two arguments has to be blank then it works on IE8.

Comment: In my case I had no winName parameter as I was using the script to open another website. Omitting the parameter break the script in IE 7, 8 and 9. I had to use '' between URL parameter and features parameter. Thanks for this information.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether it throws any javascript error?

You can use [IE8 built in javascript debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/jscript/archive/2008/03/13/jscript-debugger-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx)

Comment: Try window.open from basic phase,say window.open("/modules/mod_oneononechat/chatwindow.php") , and add parameters one by one. You will get to know when/adding what makes it stop working in IE8.

Comment: If basic itself not working, then you can at least conclude it as a setting in browser.

Comment: I am saying this approach because from IE8 Microsoft have discontinued supporting some of the parameters and supported with some new sets. So if you are using old ones, they will throw script error in IE8. Buy you said you are not getting any error!

Answer (score 0):

The [support article titled Q281679](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q281679) by Microsoft was released for MSIE 5.5/6.0. But it could be applicable for MSIE 8.

Alternatively, you could use the [X-UA-Compatible meta tag or header](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/06/10/introducing-ie-emulateie7.aspx), and see if this can be resolved by resorting to the compatibility mode (I would personally use this as a last resort, and would instead attempt to write JavaScript that does not cause IE8 to behave as described).

PS: To avoid IE8 from requiring the compatibility mode, use the services of the [W3C page validator](http://validator.w3.org/), and have the page tested in another standards compliant browser like Firefox 3 (don't forget to use Firebug and the Web Development Toolbar extensions if you use FF3).

Comment: it shows up in compatibility mode..but yea..i want it to work without having to turn it on..

Comment: Then I suspect that your page does not validate. Attempt to write standards-compliant code so that IE8 is not thrown into quirks mode. Use the W3C validator at http://validator.w3.org/ to help yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you use spaces or dashes in the window name, IE won't work (at least some versions that I used).

Comment: you can't have slashes either.

Answer (score 0):

IN IE if you open one window with `window.open()` - again if you want to open new window with `window.open()`,It will not open new window.

For this the solutions is - IN `Window.open` parameters pass this parameter `"copyhistory=no"`.

e.g:

```
WindowName = window.open('','Name','height=320,width=428,toolbar=no, 
     menubar=no,scrollbars=no, resizable=no,location=no, directories=no,    
     status=no,copyhistory=no');
```

Hope this will be helpful for you.